# Can I set global noRollbackFor policy in Spring transaction management using annotations or java config?

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

Is there a way to replace following Spring configuration in xml:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
<tx:attributes>
  <tx:method name="*" no-rollback-for="MyNoCausingRollbackException" />
</tx:attributes>
```

with annotation or java config?

My goal is to configure *each* transaction behavior in that way, so throwing `MyNoCausingRollbackException` inside method annotated with `@Transactional` won't rollback current transaction.
I would like to avoid defining such behavior each time using `Transactional(noRollbackFor = ResourceNotFoundException.class)` on each method that can throw such exception.

Comment: I guess here is an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47838868/spring-boot-transaction-manager-advice-to-roll-back-all-exceptions