# spring boot transaction manager advice to roll back all exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

Prior to Spring Boot, one was able to globally say (without having to identify on each @Transactional element) that all checked exceptions should roll back a transaction:

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" rollback-for="Exception" timeout="20"/>
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
```

How is the above achieved via Java config in the Spring Boot world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **custom annotations**

> If you find you are repeatedly using the same attributes with
>   @Transactional on many different methods, then Spring's
>   meta-annotation support allows you to define custom shortcut
>   annotations for your specific use cases. For example, defining the
>   following annotations

```
  @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
  @Transactional(rollbackFor=Exception.class)
  public @interface OrderTx {
  }
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#tx-custom-attributes

Comment: Thank you. This will work. I'll go with this unless someone has another non-intrusive method so all legacy code doesn't need to change.